# looping through object property names in actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, dynamic

I have a dynamic class that I have created

```
public dynamic class SiteZoneFileUploadVO
{       
    public var destination:String = "sitezone";
    public var siteZoneId:uint;
    public var fileType:String;
    public var fileContents:String;

    public function SiteZoneFileUploadVO()
    {
    }

}
```

when I try to iterate over this object's **property names** it only iterates the dynamically added properties.

```
        parameters.dynVar= "value";

        for(var name:String in parameters) 
        {
            trace(name);
        }
```

Even though the object has all the properties equal to a value (ive checked this in the debugger) the only **property name** that will be traced is dynVar.

How can I iterate over all the **property names** and not just the dynamically added ones?

Comment: sorry guys, I phrased the question wrong.  Im looking to iterate over the property names, not the values in the properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`describeType()`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#describeType%28%29) to get an XML with all methods and variables of your class and then filter out the properties you want to iterate over (e.g. all variables) and store them in an `XMLList`.

As the next step you would then iterate over the `XMLList` and use square bracket notation on your object to access the filtered properties by their names. However, you can only access public properties this way because `describeType()` won't look at private properties.

Comment: Baelnom speaks correctly - you can't iterate over dynamic and static properties with for (var name in parameters) - only can iterate over dynamic properties.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running flex:

Looked at a few posts, `ObjectUtil.toString` was the most promising, then looked at the flex source code for it, it uses another method `ObjectUtil.getClassInfo` which is exactly what you need. If you just want property names:

```
ObjectUtil.getClassInfo(myClass).properties
```

returns an Array of QName objects, each has a localName property which will give you a string for each property name

Answer (score 0):

Just use `trace(ObjectUtil.toString(parameters));` That should give you your entire object.

Comment: While `ObjectUtil.toString()` can be used to print out all properties of an object, it does so in a single String. That makes it imho unpractical for accessing single properties and basically completely rules out any sort of looping.

Comment: @Baelnorn - Agreed, it's an ugly, ugly dump, but useful when that's all you need. I skimmed the question too much, didn't realize the OP was looking for more than a dump